# Stop WhatsApp from being used on lost phone

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, lost-phone

I lost my Android phone, but my WhatsApp is still on. How I can stop someone who is using it?

I don't have the SIM with me. The people who found it is using my WhatsApp account. When they went online, I tried to talk but they did no reply.

Comment: Tried to lock your SIM by your provider already?

Comment: Get your provider to lock the device. Contact Whatsapp and explain the situation to them.

Answer (score 5):

[From Whatsapp](https://www.whatsapp.com/faq/en/general/24460358):

> **What do I do if my phone is lost or stolen?**
>
> In the unfortunate case that your phone gets lost or stolen, we can
>   help make sure that no one can use your WhatsApp account.
>
> As soon as possible you should call your mobile provider to lock your
>   SIM card. Then, it will not be possible to verify the account on that
>   phone again as you need to be able to receive SMS or phone calls to
>   verify an account.
>
> After you have locked the SIM in your stolen phone, you can use a new
>   SIM with the same number to activate WhatsApp on your new phone. This
>   is the fastest way to deactivate your account on the stolen phone.
>   WhatsApp can only be activated with one phone number on one device at
>   a time.
>
> If you are not ready to activate WhatsApp on a new phone with the same
>   number we can deactivate your account. Email us with your phone number
>   in the full international format as described [here](https://www.whatsapp.com/faq/en/general/21016748). Please note that
>   we are not able to help you locate your phone. Remote WhatsApp
>   deactivation from another device is not possible.
>
> Important: Even with the SIM card locked and phone service disabled,
>   WhatsApp can be used on Wi-Fi if you do not contact us with an account
>   deactivation request.
>
> **More important details about deactivated accounts**
>
> 1. When your account is deactivated, it is not completely deleted.
> 2. While your account is deactivated:
>
>    - Your name is still on your contacts' Favorites / Select Contact lists.
>    - Your contacts can send you messages, which will remain in a pending state for up to 30 days.
> 3. If you reactivate your account before it is deleted, you will receive any pending messages on your new phone and you will still be
>      in all of your group chats.
> 4. If a deactivated account is not re-activated within 30 days, it will be completely deleted.
>
> **Note:** Since your chat history is stored on your device, we cannot retrieve your previous messages.